# Route for learning Smalltalk aka Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, mit-scratch

Calling Jedi Masters of the Smalltalk universe,

I have knowledge of C++/Python/Perl and have been coding for 5+ years now.

I have to fork Scratch - MIT's Visual programming language to add support for a robotic kit. Scratch is created using Squeak, which is an implementation of Smalltalk.

I am planning to read A Little Smalltalk - By Timothy budd followed by Sqeak By Examples - By Oscar Nierstrasz [http://squeakbyexample.org/]

Do you think this is a good idea ?. What would you suggest ?. Are there free video tutorials I can watch.

End objective is to be able to make sense of scratch codebase. I want to get hang of smalltalk once before I can make sense of the (as of now) weird looking Squeak development environment and its ways.

Luke Smallwalker

Comment: [Scratch for Arduino](http://seaside.citilab.eu/scratch/arduino) may offer some interesting bits already.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I work with the core developers of Scratch for Arduino! It may be a good start for you to take a look at its code.

I think *A Little Smalltalk* goes a bit too deep for what you'll need. *Squeak by example* is, IMO, much better suited as an entry point to the language.

Also, you may want to take a look at [Prof Stef for Amber](http://amber-lang.net/learn.html), which is not an intro to Squeak but to Amber Smalltalk. Anyway the syntax is pretty much the same and it will get you a first good idea of what Smalltalk feels like.

HIH, good luck!

[edit] Yesterday I stumbled upon [this great article](http://live.exept.de/doc/miscDocuments/readingSmalltalk.pdf) explaining how to read Smalltalk code for Java/C++ developers.

Comment: Actually Prof Stef was introduced in Squeak and was adapted by the Amber project. So it usually is available/installable in every Squeak image. But good suggestions anyway.

Comment: Yup, I wrote the Amber port actually :)

Comment: I see, nice work. But it would still be good, if you would mention where the 'original' Prof Stef came from.

Answer (score 2):

check out my youtube tutorial series Squeak from the very start

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6601A198DF14788D&feature=viewall

Answer (score 2):

I have read through "Squeak By Example" and I would say it is very good. I haven't seen "A Little Smalltalk" I think it might be a little outdated because it is from 1987.

after reading "Squeak By Example" I came across [BotsInc](http://rmod.lille.inria.fr/botsinc/pier?_s=abSviICcvIAzcwf2&_k=L76Fdyv2M_dAEJAa&_n&5) it might be useful to go BotsInc even though it might seem a bit childish at first. Squeak By Example would be better to understand Smalltalk more fully.

this is a small squeak tutorial that might help too http://scratch.mit.edu/forums/viewtopic.php?id=39196

Answer (score 1):

Stephan B Wessels has a Laser game project that was really useful for me when learning Smalltalk (in Squeak). You can follow and code along here: http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/index.html

On to Smalltalk by Patrick Henry Winston is a succinct introductory book that you can get pretty cheaply used at [http://www.amazon.com/On-Smalltalk-Patrick-Henry-Winston/dp/0201498278/ref=cm_cr-mr-title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201498278)